# Call contract view method from web3

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, nodejs

I am trying to call a function on a smart contract using web3 and web3-eth-contract but I get the error `Provider does not have a request or send method to use.`

Here is the general code I am attempting:

```
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(infuraEndpoint);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const contract = new Contract(tokenAbi.abi, tokenContractAddress);
contract.methods.someFun().call()
        .on('receipt', (res) => {.....
```

I am clearly missing something about how this works, but I can't figure out what it is.  Does anyone have an example of making a call to a function on an ethereum contract from node?

Comment: While `send` returns an [event emitter](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/callbacks-promises-events.html#callbacks-promises-events), `call` doesn't.

Comment: If `someFun` is a constant (pure or view) method, then you don't need to wait for a `receipt` event. If it is a non-constant method and you want to execute it in a transaction, then you need to use `send` or similar (`sendTransaction`, `sendSignedTransaction`, etc).

Comment: Ahh, this must be where my mistake is.  It's a view method, so what is the proper way of calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll paste an [example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id32) from web3 docs for you to take a look

```
myContract.methods.myMethod(123)
.call({from:'0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'})
.then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
});
```

I also think that you need to change `new Contract` to `new web3.eth.Contract` if you are using the current version of web3.

Comment: I get this error:
```Error: Provider does not have a request or send method to use.```

Comment: Yeah that was it, I was using the wrong Contract class.  Thank You!