# How to retrieve contents of mapped struct by passing in an address

Tags: solidity, react, error

I want to retrieve a patients detail by passing in an address to the function. I managed to do this when writing tests using Mocha and I can retrieve the values with no problem. But when I tried it on the Rinkeby network it seem to give errors. Sorry, this is my first time posting here so i don't know the standard procedures to ask a question.

**Solidity Code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Record {
    
    struct Patients{
        string name;
        string age;
        string phone;
        string diseases;
    }
    
    address public owner;
    address[] public patientList;
    mapping (address => Patients) patients;
    mapping(address => bool) isApproved;
    
    function Record() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        isApproved[msg.sender] = true;
    }
    
    //Retrieve patient details from the form and save the details
    function setDetails(string _name, string _age, string _phone, string _diseases) public {
        var p = patients[owner];
        
        p.name = _name;
        p.age = _age;
        p.phone = _phone;
        p.diseases = _diseases;
        
        patientList.push(owner);
    }
    
    //Search patient details by entering a patient address (Only record owner or doctor with permission will be allowed to access)
    function searchPatient(address _address) public view returns(string, string, string, string) {
        require(isApproved[msg.sender] == true);
        return (patients[_address].name, patients[_address].age, patients[_address].phone, patients[_address].diseases);
    }
    
}
```

**Mocha Test that passed:**

```
it('can search for a patient', async () => {
        await record.methods.setDetails(
            'John', '22', '213134', 'Flu'
        ).send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });
        
        const owner = await record.methods.owner().call();

        names = await record.methods.searchPatient(owner).call();

        console.log(names[0]);
    });
```

**React Code that failed to retrieve value stored in struct:**

```
class RecordDetails extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps(props) {
        const records = await record.methods.searchPatient(props.query.address).call();
        
        return {
            address: props.query.address,
            names: records[0]
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <div>
                    {this.props.address}
                    {this.props.names}
                </div>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

export default RecordDetails;
```

**Error that is found in browser console:**
[image]

Comment: The react code is missing the `.call()` at the end of `searchPatient(props.query.address)`.

Comment: Thanks, man! But I tried it and it didn't fix it and still gave the exact same error. I also tried calling the values using remix and it works, mocha test also works. Just don't seem to work when retrieving in the front end.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the require from `searchPatient`? Can you check that `record` is properly initialized? Can you call other methods like `owner()`?

Comment: Tried removing require from searchPatient still didn't work. I called owner and its working. But whenever i try to retrieve a name of patient, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a repo? As is I can't test, the solidity code seems right. I don't know much about react so I can't say if the code is wrong. So my guess is that there's something wrong on the client side.

Comment: Yes sure! Here is my repo: https://github.com/JasonnLim/Blockchain-MedicalRecords

Comment: I downloaded the repo, modified a bit to test with ganache, it worked without issue, I was able to create a couple of records. I'm using node 10 LTS, brave with its crypto wallet accessing ganache at 127.0.0.1:8545.

Comment: Wow, thanks for updating on this!! May i know how did you do it and what codes did you change? So is it a problem with the front end code?

Comment: I did a couple of changes to web3.js and deploy.js to point to ganache rpc `http://127.0.0.1:8545`, adjust deploy mnemonic, adjust deployed address in register.js, then use this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/91537 to connect to crypto wallet. I'd use web3-react or similar instead.

Comment: But other than changing to deploy in ganache, did you change anything in the react code?

Comment: I haven't touched react code at all. I'd guess that the problem might be the connection to metamask try replacing in web3.js by `if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.ethereum !== undefined) { window.ethereum.enable(); web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum); } else { ...`. The problem with the code is that now it has to be async to await for `enable()` and you need to refactor that part.

Comment: I just refactored according to how you told me to, but it still doesn't work ohhno.  `async () => {await window.web3.currentProvider.enable();} web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);` I added these 2 statements in the `if(typeof window...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who is facing the same problem, here is how i solved it (After weeks of debugging finally found the error). The problem is with the React code and just changing one line of code will solve this issue.

**Original React Code**

```
const records = await record.methods.searchPatient(props.query.address).call();
```

**Changed React Code**

```
const addr = props.query.address;
const records = await record.methods.searchPatient(addr).call({from: addr});
```