# Get a state variable from unverified contract

Tags: solidity, python, brownie

Is it possible to get a variable state from existing contract which was not verified but I know what variables, functions etc. the contract contains?

Assume, we have the following script (using Brownie, the name of variable is `variable_to_obtain`):

```
from brownie import Contract
from scripts.helpers import get_account


def get_variable_of_instance(instance_address):
    account = get_account()
    instance_contract = Contract.from_explorer(instance_address, {"from": account})
    variable_to_return = instance_contract.variable_to_obtain()
    return variable_to_return


def main():
    var = get_variable_of_instance("address_of_instance")
    print(var)
```

Any idea?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way how to do this depends on the contract that you want to extract the variable from.

If the contract normally provides a function to query this variable you just need to know the correct function id to query it.

If this is not the case then you can use `eth_getStorageAt` to query the storage at a specific slot for that contract, but for this you will require some knowledge about the internals of that contract.

Comment: Thank you very much @Richard for providing me with hints. Could you please guide me how to query to the function of the smart contract (if I know its id)?

Comment: Something like https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91510/call-contract-view-method-from-web3 should be the way to go