# How to read ERC-1155 NFT metadata without 'uri()' method implemented

Tags: nft, erc-1155, meta-data

I need to read an ERC-1155 NFT token metadata.

The smart contract code does not implement the 'uri()' method.

How can we retrieve it's metadata, or at least the metadata's url/URI?

The smart contract is in polygon network, at the address 0x60576a64851c5b42e8c57e3e4a5cf3cf4eeb2ed6.

The actual NFT can be seen at https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0x60576a64851c5b42e8c57e3e4a5cf3cf4eeb2ed6/1655/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smart contract you referred to actually has a `uri()` method.
You might not be able to find it because the contract is a proxy contract.

In order to read what's behind the proxy, look at it on [PolygonScan](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x60576a64851c5b42e8c57e3e4a5cf3cf4eeb2ed6#readProxyContract).
`uri()` method shows that you need to call this url to retrieve metadata of NFT #1655: `https://api.mintkudos.xyz/metadata/1655`

Comment: Thanks! I actually got to that point. My problem is I wanted to read it from JavaScript. I think I need to study what a proxy contract is. I want to build a JavaScript NFT reader.

Comment: @AndreSoeiro try this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91510/call-contract-view-method-from-web3